# Calculate average of a column in two dataframes, then plot the averages of each dataframe in a barplot with a specific label?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

New to Stack Overflow here, so apologies if this is a dumb question.

I am wondering, how I calculate the average of two dataframes for a specific column, then plot the averages of the two dataframes on a barplot with a specific label?

For example, consider the two fictional dataframes below.

- **Schools (North):**

```
ID     NAME     NUMBER_GIRLS
----------------------------
1     SCHOOL_1       32
2     SCHOOL_2       12
3     SCHOOL_3       26
```

- **Schools (South):**

```
ID     NAME     NUMBER_GIRLS
----------------------------
1     SCHOOL_1       56
2     SCHOOL_2       33
3     SCHOOL_3       34
```

Now, from calculating the average `NUMBER_GIRLS` for both schools, I get this:

- Schools (North) = 23.3
- Schools (South) = 41

Therefore, from calculating the averages for both of these dataframes, how do I plot them on a barplot so that Schools (North) is labelled as "North", and Schools (South) is labelled as "South"?

Something that looks like this:

[What I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZHo4.png)

Any help is much appreciated, as I want to do something similar to this but with more dataframes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

objects = ('North', 'South')
y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
performance = [23.3,41]

plt.bar(y_pos, performance, align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)
plt.title('Average Number of Girls')

plt.show()
```

You can replace 23.3 and 41 with Northdf[NUMBER_GIRLS].mean() and Southdf[NUMBER_GIRLS].mean() or whatever the dataframe names are

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is what I am trying to accomplish, so a huge thanks. However, when using the ```sns.barplot``` function, I cannot get the confidence interval to show up on my plot. Any reason why?